# How is the check function working in this program of Priority Queue

Tags: c, data-structures

This is the program for priority queue data structures. Can someone explain me the check function in this program? I understand that it is used to check the priority of the inserted elements but i am a little confused how is it doing that and what was the need of nested loops in check function.

Also please explain the for loop initialization and condition part for `j` why did we do `rear+1` and why is `j>i`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define max 3

int q[max],front=0,rear=-1;

void insert_by_p()
{
    if(rear==max-1)
    {
        printf("overflow\n");return;
    }
    printf("please enter the element\n");

    int a;

    scanf("%d",&a);
    check(a);
    rear++;
}

void check(int a)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=front;i<=rear;i++)
    {
        if(a<=q[i])
        {
            for(j=rear+1;j>i;j--)
                q[j]=q[j-1];
            q[i]=a;
            return;
        }
    }
    q[i]=a;
}

void display()
{
    if(rear==-1||front>rear)
    {
        printf("underflow\n");return;
    }
    printf("Q items:");
    for(int i=front;i<=rear;i++)
    {
        printf("%d,",q[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void delete_by_p()
{
    if(rear==-1||front>rear)
    {
        printf("underflow\n");return;
    }
    printf("the deleted element is %d\n",q[front++]);
}

int main()
{
    int a;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("please choose one option:\n1.insert\n2.delete\n3.display\n4.exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        switch(a)
        {
            case 1: insert_by_p();
            break;
            case 2: delete_by_p();
            break;
            case 3: display();
            break;
            case 4: exit(0);
            break;
            default:printf("Wrong choice\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: So i got comments regarding if the code was right or who provided the code. Dont worry about that the code is working perfectly fine and it was given to me by my professor. Unlike linear queue, priority queue will arrange the elements according to their priority(here max element highest priority) the dequeue operation would happen as per the priority

Comment: Please explain your understanding of what priority queues are supposed to achieve. That is needed to judge your level of understanding. Especially since the function `check()` is so unhelpfully named .... What is the context of you trying to understand this? Do you have access to the author of that code?

Comment: Ask whoever wrote the code.  Failing that use a debugger and step-through the `check()` function to see how it works (and if it works).  You are asking us to analyse code on the assumption that is is also correct.  It may be, but it would be a lot of effort to work that out.  Learning to use a debugger to answer these sort of questions will be much faster than posting questions on SO - in the long run.

Comment: What makes you think that it does work? Reading the code I have many doubts. Please provide input for which the code does do anything meaningful and explain which meaning it has. Only that makes a [mre]. Also have a look at the [tour] and at [ask] please.

Comment: "_the code is working perfectly fine_" - bold claim! It is seriously flawed.   Try adding three items then deleting one item, then adding an item.  The queue has just two items, but you cannot add a third.  If you delete the two items, you have an empty queue and cannot add any items!

Answer (score 0):

Considering:

```
int q[max],front=0,rear=-1;
```

Then in `insert_by_p()`:

```
check(a);
rear++;
```

When `check()` is called `a` has not yet been inserted and `rear` refers to the "old" end (or -1 on the first insertion).  So in check, `rear` is one less than the insertion location.  Hence `rear + 1` in the for loop, and `j > i` because the loop is iterating in reverse *toward* `i`.

With respect to how `check()` actually works, well to start with it does not "*check the priority of the inserted elements*" - it actually performs the insertion - it is misleadingly named.  The outer loop iterates through the non-deleted elements of `q[]`.  The inner loop moves elements of `q[]` to make space for the insertion of `a`.

To be honest the code is not great;

- An array is an inappropriate data structure for this, requiring data to be moved non-deterministically for each insertion.  A doubly-linked list would be more appropriate.
- `front` and `rear` are only ever incremented.  Everytime `delete_by_p()` is called, the queue capacity is effectively reduced.  It is a "leaky" algorithm.
- `check()` is used in `insert_by_p()` *before* it is declared.
- since `a` is inserted by `check()`, then the `rear++` should be done there too (and `check()` is a bad name for a function that actually modifies the data).
- `check()` has two exit points with one deeply nested - that is nasty, and can lead to errors.  For example if you were to move the `rear++` to `check()` as I suggest; you have to add it in two places.
- I am sure there are other issues - those are just the ones immediately obvious.